# Ionic build failed with exception on mac

Tags: ionic-framework

Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 25].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: You need to install SDK with android studio tools

Comment: I have install SDK I get the same error

Comment: Do you have install SDK 23? You need to install Android SDK 25

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have installed the Android SDK Platform 25 in Android SDK Manager

[image]